# Prove lower semicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis

> $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, ($A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$) is lower semi-continuous if   for every $x_{0}\in A, y<f(x_{0})$ there exists a neighborhood U of $x_0$ such that $f(x)>y$ for all x $\in U\cap A$.
>
> Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ let $g(x)=\sup_{\delta>0}\{\inf_{|y-x|<\delta}f(y)\}$ Show $g$ is lower semicontinuous.

My thoughts:

In previous sections I have re-parameterized the definition to be "for every $x_{0}\in A, \epsilon>0$ there exists a neighborhood U of $x_0$ such that $f(x)>f(x_0)-\epsilon$ for all x $\in U\cap A$. "
I think the notation of g(x) somehow looks like the definition of liminf...

My solution for now:

Given any epsilon there is delta_0 and delta_1 such that

$x\in B_{\delta0}(x_0)=U, B_{\delta1}(x) \subset B_{\delta0}(x_0)$

$g(x_0)-\epsilon< inf f(B_{\delta0}(x_0))\leq inf f(B_{\delta1}(x)) \leq g(x)$

Answer (score 1):

It's easier if we rephrase this: you want to prove that if $x_0\in U_a:=\{f>a\}$ for a fixed real number $a$, and if $U_a$ is open for all $a$ such that $x_0\in U_a$, then $f(x_0)\le \underset{x\to x_0}\lim\inf f(x).$

Let $\epsilon>0.$ Since $U_{f(x_0)-\epsilon}$ is open  (it contains $x_0),\ f(x)> f(x_0)-\epsilon$ on some neighborhood $V$ of $x_0$, which implies that $f(x_0)\le \underset{x\to x_0}\lim\inf f(x)=g(x_0).$

That is, $g(x_0)\ge f(x_0)>a,$ which is what we want.